# change json format from 2 array into 1 arrays

Tags: php, mysql

i want to change json format from this below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notification_title] => Payment has processed completely! Kindly check you account.
            [notification_message] => Thank you for being our trusted driver and manage the ads on your car carefully. Your payment has proceded succesfully. Kindly check your account or credit.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [notification_title] => Payment has processed completely! Kindly check you account.
            [notification_message] => Terimakasih atas kepercayaan dan kerjasama Anda bersama KarAds. Pembayaran Anda telah kami proses, silahkan lakukan pengecekan pada rekening bank atau kredit Anda pada compensation info. Kami tunggu partisipasi Anda untuk kampanye iklan lainnya. 
        )

)
```

into this below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notification_title] => Payment has processed completely! Kindly check you account.
            [notification_message] => Thank you for being our trusted driver and manage the ads on your car carefully. Your payment has proceded succesfully. Kindly check your account or credit.
            [notification_message_ind] => Terimakasih atas kepercayaan dan kerjasama Anda bersama KarAds. Pembayaran Anda telah kami proses, silahkan lakukan pengecekan pada rekening bank atau kredit Anda pada compensation info. Kami tunggu partisipasi Anda untuk kampanye iklan lainnya.    
)
```

the purpose why i want to do this, i want to split the record into separate column.

My current code to explode them.

```
$post_array = array(
                'notification_title' => $this->input->post('notification_title'),
                'notification_message' => $this->input->post('notification_message'),
                'notification_type' => $this->input->post('notification_type'),
                'notification_language' => $this->input->post('notification_language')
            );


        $data = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($post_array as $key=>$val) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($val as $k=>$v) {
                $data[$i][$key] = $v;
                $i++;
            }
        }

        print_r($data);
```

Comment: you can use json_encode

Comment: hi @scaisEdge i use that print using json_encode, but my question is how to split the json format

Comment: You can't have two elements in the same key in an array, so the second notification_message will overwrite the first one.

Comment: How if i change the key ?, please see on above